# Efficient way to reconstruct base table from changes

Tags: postgresql

I have a table consisting of `products` (with ID's, ~15k records) and another table `price_changes` (~88m records) recording a change in the `price` for a given `productID` at a given `changedate`.

I'm now interested in the price for each product at given points in time (say every 2 hours for a year, so altogether ~ 4300 points; altogether resulting in ~64m data points of interest). While it's very straight forward to determine the price for a given product at a given time, it seems to be quite time-consuming to determine all 64m data points.

My approach is to pre-populate a new target table `fullprices` with the data points of interest:

```
insert into fullprices(obsdate,productID) 
    select  obsdate, productID from targetdates, products
```

and then update each price observation in this new table like this:

```
update fullprices f set price = (select price from price_changes where 
                           productID = f.productID and date < f.obsdate
                           order by date desc
                           limit 1)
```

which should give me the most recent price change in each point in time.

Unfortunately, this takes ... well, ages. Is there any better way to do it?

== Edit: My tables are created as follows: ==

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
   productID uuid NOT NULL,
   name text NOT NULL,  
   CONSTRAINT products_pkey PRIMARY KEY (productID )
);

CREATE TABLE price_changes
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    productID uuid NOT NULL,
    price smallint,
    date timestamp NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX idx_pc_date
    ON price_changes USING btree
    (date);

CREATE INDEX idx_pc_productID
    ON price_changes USING btree
    (productID);

CREATE TABLE targetdates
(
    obsdate timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE fullprices
(
     obsdate timestamp NOT NULL,
    productID uuid NOT NULL,
    price smallint
);
```

Comment: Your "dates" are in fact timestamps - is the time part relevant there? Or do you only consider the "day" when checking for changes.

Comment: 0) dont use `date` as an identifier 1) Your time-axis is inverted: `productID = f.productID and date < f.obsdate
                           order by date desc` -->> `productID > f.productID and date > f.obsdate
                           order by date asc` 2) you need a *composite* index on `price_changes(productID, date);`

Comment: Yes, time is also releveant (prices may change several times a day). Sorry for confusing nomenclature.

Comment: @joop, 1) no I think it's correct, I'm interested in the latest price change before `f.obsdate` . 2) Ok will try that.

Comment: Or create the new table in one sweep: `select  obsdate, productID from targetdates, products` --> `Create table complete_table AS SELECT  obsdate, productID, ... from targetdates td JOIN products p ON td.productID = p.productID` ; (which could also be a plain query, or even a view)

Comment: Targetdates doesn't have productID. Besides, that query is not the issue; the update afterwards is.

Comment: TargetDates is never populated, so the carthesian product is empty.

Comment: On second thought: you want targetdates to be a *calendar table* Do the timestamps in there match the existing timestamps exactly? Or do you need to interpolate (or use the most recent available point in time for the product ?)

Comment: Targetdates is e.g. bi-hourly, i.e., Jan 1st 13:00, Jan 1st. 14:00 etc. Then I do the cross join b/c that's exactly what I'm eventually interested in: Prices for all products at those dates specified in targetdates.

Comment: @joop, changes in `price_changes` can be anytime in between, so I'm always interested in the most recent change when populating `fullprices`.

Comment: Something like this http://rextester.com/DZZR48429 maybe?

Comment: @joop, adding the index did the job ... do you want to write it as answer so iI can accept it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, tried it in and did not finish within 2 yours (whereas the original query now finished within 15min).. thank you anyways.

Comment: @bonifaz: your update finished in 15 minutes? You said it took "ages".

Comment: 15 minutes after I added the index suggested by @joop; before it did not finish at all within 24 hours.

Comment: Well, it is a *natural* primary key for the given table. [hint: before you start thinking about (secondary) indexes, think about keys (and how they relate)]